# how to make a spring jpa/correct repository when having mandatory relationships?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the following database which allows users to rent books in a book shop:
[image]

The entity class Book needs to have a Category as well as BookDescription when saved.

Those Book class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Book {

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "book_description_id")
private BookDescription bookDescription;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Category category;

//omitted fields, getters, setters & other relations
}
```

I was checking out Spring Data JPA. It has a signature of

```
CrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>
```

which means that I will have

```
CrudRepository<Book, String>
```

but how will I save a book?

So, generally, the user will submit a form, I will bind a BookUIObject which will contain all the details needed to save a book, pass it to a BookService witch will extract from it 3 objects: Book ( a specific implementation), Category and BookDescription. The question is will the service hook up the book relations and call the general repository.save(Book) or it will call a method like repository.save(Book, Category, BookDescription)?

Also, should I bind directly the data from the user into entity classes, or do like I said, bind to a general BookUIObject and let the service extract from it the entity classes?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you will have to call BookReporitory.save(book). Book has cascaring Persist for both of the relations, so if you have set the BookDescription and the Category on the book instance you save, they will also be persisted. If you didn't have cascading persist, you would have to save them using their JPARepository (unless they already existed in the Persistence context).

One thing that is important to understand in this example is that if you create a new category object and set it on a book and save the book a new category is created in the DB. So if the UI posts category=sic-fi, you have to check if the category already exists, if it does then you must used the managed category, and set that on the book rather than creating another "sci-fi" category. This is the reason I would not have cascading persist on the Category relation, because I would rather have a constraint violation because a category didn't exist, instead of an new category sci-if when someone miss spelled it in the UI.

I do not recommending binding forms directly to JPA entities, because you always need to fetch entities from JPA, as you have to use the managed versions, so in my experience it is better to have another set of beans for form binding.

Another thing that jumps out if the lack of nullable=false in @JoinColumn. If a book can't exist without being in a Category it is vital that this is communicated to the database, and if you generate tables from the JPA metadata model, this is how it is done. If I could give only one recommendation when working with databases/JPA it is to be overzealous with NOT NULL. It is a 100 time easier to get a constraint violation when you insert, than to get a NullPointerException later and have to check every possible code-path that could end up calling save and checking if the argument could be null.

In addition I would recommend that you set of some time to understand the concept of the EntityManager and the Persistence Context, most of the mistakes/assumptions developers make come back to the persistence context and how the 4 entity states work.